# How to directly re-use the dumped content of `.rodata`, `.data` and `.bss` section?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, nasm

OK, so basically I want to **re-use** the content from dumped `.rodata` `data` and `bss` section from ELF on Linux 32bit.

The dump command:

```
objdump -s -j .text elf_binary
objdump -s -j .rodata elf_binary
objdump -s -j .data elf_binary
```

and for the `.bss` section, I am preparing to re-use a bunch of `00000000` which has the same size of the `bss` section.

It works fine when I re-use it in `nasm` assembler in this way.

```
.section rodata
S_label1: db 0x01
         db 0x02
         ....  
.section data
        db 0x01
S_label2:  db 0x02
         ....
.section bss
S_label3: db 0x00
         db 0x00
         ....

nasm -f elf test.s
```

But basically my question is that:

how to re-use these dumped sections in `gas` asssembler?

Basically `gas` has a different assemble style, and apparently the data sections representations are different...

I tried for several times and I still can not find the solution..

Did I clearly demonstrate my question..? Could anyone give me some help?

=======update==========

So basically I want to re-use the `rodata` `data` and `bss` sections dumped from another binary.

For example, here is the content of `rodata` section

```
03000000 01000200 0a0a556e 736f7274
65642061 72726179 2069733a 20200020
25642000 0a0a536f 72746564 20617272
61792069 733a2020 00
```

and I can re-use it in this way:

```
label1: 
db 0x03
db 0x00
db 0x00
db 0x00
label2: 
db 0x01
db 0x00
db 0x02
db 0x00
.....

mov eax, label1      // of course I will guarantee that I use it correctly
....
```

Basically in `nasm`, I can easily re-use them in the above way, but my question is that , how can I re-use it in `gas` (or directly use `gcc`) in a similiar way?

Is it possible?

Comment: Reuse for what exactly? Please describe the overall problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: I believe the poster is trying to reuse the content of these sections in an assembly program he/she's writing.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Hi, I updated my question..

Comment: @yaspr Hi, I modifyed my question... Is it clear now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an assembly programmer I would say that `gas` is rarely used to assemble external code. The task of calling `gas` is usually left to the compiler, and most of the assembly that `gas` has to handle in real life is either `inlined` inside `C` or `C++` code or comes from a compiler. But, I believe [this](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/teaching/eecs373-f11/readings/Assembler.pdf) document by **Dean Elsner**, **Jay Fenlanson** & **friends** is by far the best reference I managed to rely on for quite sometime. It has been updated many times and it covers the 2.19.51 version.

The easy way would be to use **GCC** I would say :

```
  //Just to avoid make a point :]
  typedef unsigned char byte;

  //
  byte lbl1[] = { 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, ... }, 
       lbl2[] = { 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, ... };

  //I prefer Intel syntax rather than AT&T, it's somehow cleaner !
  __asm__("intel_syntax noprefix                 ;"
          "mov eax, %0                           ;"
          "mov ebx, %1                           ;"
          "att_syntax prefix                     ;"
          :                        //output
          : "r" (lbl1), "r" (lbl2) //input
          : "%eax", "%ebx");       //clobber
```

Well, this is a nice way if you want to concentrate on the assembly code (which is how I do it when I optimize code by hand).

Now, let me explain it a bit. First, you have two arrays containing the retrieved data, nothing fancy. Then you get the assembly code. If you're not familiar with `inlined` assembly I would recommend you [this](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) link, though I'll briefly go over my code.
The `__asm__` directive lets you insert assembly instructions anywhere in a code. At first I tell the assembler that I'll be using Intel's syntax (no % prefix for registers, ...), then I move the content of the register %0 in `eax`, and then the content of %1 in `ebx` (%0 is the pointer for **lbl1**, %1 is the pointer for **lbl2**). Then, I switch to AT&T syntax for the rest of the parameters. After the first **:** you can specify output variables. After the second **:** you can specify inputs. In here I passed **lbl1** & **lbl2** and I used **"r"** to let the compiler handle register allocation. You can specify the registers if you know what you're doing. After the last **:** you have to declare the registers used inside the code so that the compiler frees them & uses them for the remaining code generation steps.

Answer (score 1):

thanks @yaspr for his excellent answer.

So in this post I was asking that

**How to re-use `.rodata` `.data` and `.bss` sections' contents?**

Here is my answer:

you can quickly go this way once you dumped all the content of these sections, I use a hello world code to demostrate it:

```
.section .text
.globl  main
main:
push   %ebp
mov    %esp,%ebp
and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
sub    $0x20,%esp
fldl   S_80484f0     // lift the conceret address into symbol
fstpl  0x18(%esp)
fldl   0x18(%esp)
fstpl  0x4(%esp)
movl   $S_80484e0,(%esp) // lift the conceret address into symbol
call   printf
leave
ret
nop
nop
nop

.section .rodata

S_80484e0:
.long 0x6c6c6568
.long 0x6f77206f
.long 0x20642c72
.long 0x000a6625

S_80484f0:
.long 0x00000000
.long 0x40240000
```

To @yaspr about AT&T vs. Intel style:

It is obviously that Intel style is much more clear that AT&T:)

However, in the current project I am struggling on, I find it might not be very easy to use `nasm` inside a bunch of GNU tools(`objdump` `objcopy` `ld` and others...)

IMHO, Even though `objdump` can disassemble in `Intel` style, I still encounter a bunch of problems/unclear issues, especially after comparing the disassemble results between `objdump` and `IDAPro`

Comment: Well, you have to keep in mind that IDA & objdump do not perform disassembly the same way (not the same algorithms). `objdump` uses `linear sweep` which is a static disassembly technique that can give erroneous results. Especially if data is mixed up with instructions (shellcodes for example). You should trust none of tools you're using blindly, cross-reference their output if you want to efficient. Each one has its flaws & its strengths. I can assure you that using `NASM` with `GNU` tools wouldn't affect your work, though it your final choice. And, using multiple tools is a good way to learn.

Comment: @yaspr Thank you for your reply! Yes, I know the difference in disassemble algorithm, so actually in the  current project, I was trying to use `IDAPro` because it is believed the best, however, even though it is an excellent tool, I still find some un-match between the goal we want to achieve and `IDAPro` can support (disassemble binary for analysis).

Comment: There's no such thing as the "best tool". There are only sharp & well documented users. `IDAPro` offers many features which can help you perform excellent analysis & recover lots of information about the target binary file. The most interesting thing about `IDAPro` is that it's scriptable. And that is not the case of most other tools.